# How to enable IE mode in Edge browser (Version 83.0.478.61 and up) for a site?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, compatibility, microsoft-edge

Is there an easy way to enable IE mode on the new Edge (Chromium) browser.
Recent version have removed the flag for IE integration and this functionality seems to be pretty well hidden and obscured with 'special' flags and xml compatility lists.
The best 'guide' that I could find is this one: https://byteben.com/bb/enable-ie-mode-and-use-a-site-list-in-edge-chromium-with-microsoft-endpoint-manager/

But, even with the guide, I was unable to determine how to correctly set up the 'sites.xml' to work correctly. The microsoft documentation for IE mode seems to be a maze of links leading so some 'Enterprise Edge templates' which I could not figure out what they represent or even if they apply to me (I'm not in any 'enterprise').
Does anyone have a simple tutorial or step by step instructions on how to set up the IE mode in a non-active-directory environment?

Thanks.

Comment: [Steps to enable Internet Explorer Mode in new Microsoft Edge](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-internet-explorer-mode-in-new-microsoft-edge/),

Comment: @davidpostill This flag no longer exists in the latest version.

Comment: @DaliborČarapić - Were you able to get this working? I'm on version 83.0.478.64 and also don't see the flag available. Is the only way to enable this now via Group Policy?

Comment: @p_fitz No, I have no solution at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, the article that you referenced to, gave you all the hints that you need.
Look at `Verify IE Mode Configuration` section. It shows the result of all the complicated settings is just a registry key. It makes sense since that is what Microsoft keeps messing over and over again.

So, here is what you need to do to enable IE mode.

1. Turn on IE mode by the registry:

   - Open the registry:  `WindowsKey + R` -> `regedit` -> enter
   - Access Edge's item: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`
   - Create if not exist following key-value:

   ```
      |------------------------------------| -----------| ------------------- |
      | name                               | type       | value               |
      |----------------------------------- | ---------- | ------------------- |
      |InternetExplorerIntegrationLevel    | REG_DWORD  | 1                   |
      |InternetExplorerIntegrationSiteList | REG_SZ     | C:\\ie_site_list.xml|
   ```
2. Create a `ie_site_list.xml` with content similar to below:

   ```
   <site-list version="1">
     <created-by>
       <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
       <version>10.0.14357.1004</version>
       <date-created>09/20/2020 19:16:42</date-created>
     </created-by>
     <site url="www.yoursite1.com">
       <compat-mode>Default</compat-mode>
       <open-in>IE11</open-in>
     </site>
     <site url="www.yoursite2.com">
       <compat-mode>Default</compat-mode>
       <open-in>IE11</open-in>
     </site>
   </site-list>
   ```

   Keep repeating the followings block and change the `url` for all of your IE sites:

   ```
      <site url="www.yoursite2.com">
        <compat-mode>IE7Enterprise</compat-mode>
        <open-in>IE11</open-in>
      </site>
   ```

   You save this file to `C:\\ie_site_list.xml`. If you choose a different destination, remember to change the path in the registry, too.

   You could use “Enterprise Mode Site List Manager” to create and manage this config file. But since it just a text file, just something like `notepad++` is enough.
3. Confirm that Edge loaded this configuration:

   Go to [edge://compat/enterprise](http://edge://compat/enterprise), you should see the IE sites already there.
   If you haven't restart Edge, you may need to click on `Force update` button.

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed your instructions and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is still working for Edge91 (May-June 2021). I spent some time looking for a solution until I found this answer. It worked for me on several different computers.

Comment: This still works in Windows 11 Insider Build 20000.51. Amazing steps. Microsoft has made it extremely difficult to open sites in IE 11 mode. Needed it for compatibility reasons. Quite a draconian step by Microsoft.